# Transform PDF to HTML, keep layout

Tags: html, pdf

What methods are there to transform a PDF to HTML? It could be anything - online service, software, library. (Opensource preferred. In the last case, php or python would be preferred.) It has to keep the original layout (including page numbers, footnotes and such), keep the images (combining them to one single background image per page is acceptable) and keep the links. It should preferably output valid XHTML and clean up PDF features such as ligatures, but if there is some post-processing required, I can live with that. Something with a clean, relatively semantic HTML output would be great.

The closest one I found was [zamzar.org](http://zamzar.org/), but it choked on links. (Also, the HTML output is an ugly heap of absolutely positioned divs and needs post-processing because of encoding problems.)

Comment: Maybe this should be on superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library, and I found it good to parse the PDF structure (I used it to search for text).
It's a library that parses a PDF and creates an object model out of it, so you will need to code the HTML generator, but it should be not too difficult.

Answer (score 5):

I know two options. Both look visually very similar, but the output is for sure not semantic.

### Python: PyMuPDF

Install PyMuPDF: `pip install pymupdf`

```py
import fitz

def to_html(filepath: str):
    doc = fitz.open(filepath)
    for i, page in enumerate(doc):
        text = page.getText("html")
        with open(f"pymupdf-page-{i}.html", "w") as fp:
            fp.write(text)
    doc.close()
```

### pdftohtml

Within the debian sources ([this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftohtml))

```
pdftohtml -c
```

Answer (score 4):

Process the PDFs using PDFtoHTMLEx which produces pixel perfect presentational HTML markup (positioned divs).

To get semantic HTML, you can post process the documents using  [transcript.py](https://github.com/fmalina/transcript) (I am the author). This produces semantic HTML including headings, paragraphs, lists and data tables. Bear in mind the tags are reconstructed (not extracted) because the python code is looking for visual design conventions and decides based on the layout. Structure tags and semantic information is not normally present in a PDF.

Comment: Is your script Python 3 only?

Comment: It is indeed, would you be interested in Python 2.7 compatibility? It's not a big deal, I am just a purist.

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago I was using [ABBYY PDF Transformer](http://pdftransformer.abbyy.com/) and it was nice for simple documents

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at http://www.jpedal.org/html_index.php?