# PDF to HTMl in Python 3.5

Tags: html, pdf

I want to convert PDF to HTML in Python3.5.

I used following code:
import pdftotree

pdftotree.parse(pdf_file, html_path, model_type=None, model_path=None, favor_figures=True, visualize=False)

But its takes more than 30 minutes to convert into html and data is also missing.

So please suggest me some other approach.

Comment: I am stuck on this.please suggest me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform PDF to HTML, keep layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794269/transform-pdf-to-html-keep-layout)